# Powershell@2 Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: powershell, rest, azure-pipelines

I added Powershell script in my Azure pipeline task to get product version and update a file from the fetched data.
Hostname is in variable `$EndpointQA`

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Update meta file with latest product version'
  inputs:
     targetType: 'inline'
     script: |
       $url = "$(EndpointQA)/api/status"
       $status = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url
       ((Get-Content -path "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/SitecorePackages/Import/Data/meta" -Raw) -replace '{product_version}', $status.product_version) | Set-Content -Path $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/SitecorePackages/Import/Data/meta
```

This works in my Windows Powershell but when I run the pipeline, I got an error `Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.`
Any idea how to fix this?
[Screenshot of the error in pipeline task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIzwO.png)

Edit:
I added parenthesis in my Azure variable and it works. Now I got a different error:

```
The term 'status.product_version' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

[Response from Invoke-RestMethod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4Ynm.png)

Edit 2:
It's now working after removing parenthesis in my Native Powershell variable.

Comment: Is `$EndpointQA` a (Az) pipeline variable? If so, use variable macro like: `"$(EndpointQA)/api/status"`

Comment: Thanks, that works! Now I'm seeing another error `The term 'status.product_version' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.` Any idea what I did wrong in here?

Comment: Other way around - `$status` is a native PowerShell variable, so the syntax is `$status.product_version`

Comment: You save the day. Thank you so much for helping this newbie.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up PowerShell's native variable syntax with Azure pipelines' variable expansion macro syntax.

For native PowerShell variables, the syntax is `$Name`, or `${Name}`:

```
$status.product_version
# or
${status}.product_version
```

For expansion of external variables supplied by the pipeline invoker, the macro syntax is `$(Name)`:

```
"$(EndpointQA)/api/status"
```